# I want to make Edit text clickable so that when i click on it, it should show a text like one android studio

Tags: android-studio

this is my code I want to add a text whenever I click on edit text.

```
    `jet1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
     jet1.setText("One");
     }
     });`
```

Comment: Your question are unclear. Please explain _it should show a text like one android studio_ mean.

Comment: It's done I was  making a clickable Edit text so that when I click on that it will show some text which I had used in my java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an `editText` clickable

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // do things you want
                    }
                });
```